# how to change date format in mongodb

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I have created mongodb collection using nodejs as below:

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TTTUsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password:String,
   active: Boolean,
   created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', TTTUsersSchema);
```

Since creating record the default date is stored as Tue Nov 13 2018 
20:53:47 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) so when I fetch this field then it 
is displayed in HTML as above. I want to display it in DD/MM/YY HH:MM 
format.

Where I need to change? In HTML UI level? or at Mondgodb collection level.

Please help.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't store dates as Strings (check your collection with a mongodb viewer client). How do you access the date field to arrive at the given string? Are you sure you're not just seeing a stringified `Date` object?

Comment: F.ex. from Firefox JS console: `new Date().toString()` -> 
`"Thu Jan 31 2019 23:10:09 GMT+0200 (EET)"`

Answer (score 2):

Time stamps should always be stored in a consistent way, e.g. like `ISODate()` in MongoDB, and always be handled in the code in a consistent way, e.g. like `Date` object in Javascript.

Only when you

1. present a time stamp to a user as string, or
2. parse a time string from the user

then you do conversions.

Unfortunately JavaScript `Date` object is severely limited, so I would suggest to use a package like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) which offers lots of formatting capabilities:

```javascript
const moment = require('moment');

// date is a Date object you got, e.g. from MongoDB
const time = moment(date);
console.log(time.format("DD/MM/YY HH:mm"));
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan.
My query is now where to write this code? While sending the query result to html page? or in Schema.js file

my code is as below:
var emp = require('../model/Employee');
emp.findone({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err,employee){
   res.render('../views/emp/show', {emp: employee});
};

Comment: Yes, this code will need to go into the code that renders your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your date time at view layer.

- one option is to format at your controller if you are using MVC or at the layer that produce view model.
- the another option is to format at html using javascript. You may need to use lib like moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Assume current day is Tue Nov 13 2018 20:53:47 GMT+0000
Use `.toDateString()`

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toDateString());
```

It will display:

```
Tue Nov 13 2018
```

Comment: Please use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).